# How to store category and subcategory in flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please, help me I am developing an e-commerce app in Flutter with Firestore. The problem I am having is how can I store category and subcategory? And also if I want to display subcategory in relating to category how can I do that too. Please, I help do not know how I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution I can think of would be to use a single top-level collection of products, that might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- products (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- productId
   |     |     |
   |     |     --- category: "Sport"
   |     |     |
   |     |     --- subcategory: "Basket"
   |     |     |
   |     |     --- productNae: "Basketball"
   |     |
   |     --- productId
   |           |
   |           --- category: "Sport"
   |           |
   |           --- subcategory: "Tenis"
   |           |
   |           --- productNae: "Tennis Ball"
   |
   --- categoryNames (collection)
          |
          --- Sport
          |     |
          |     --- subcategories: [Basket, Tenis]
          |
          --- Fashion
                |
                --- subcategories: [Traditional, Accessories]
```

In this way, you can get all sports products using the following query:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: 'Sport')
```

If you want to get all Tenis products, the following query is required:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('products')
    .where('category', isEqualTo: 'Sport')
    .where('subcategory', isEqualTo: 'Tenis')
```

Firestore allows you to chain multiple `where()` calls, so you can filter your products as needed.

Moreover, to display a list of categories, simply get a reference to the `categoryNames` collection and list all document keys. If you want after that to display all subcategories, simply get all elements that exist in the `subcategories` array and display them again in a list.

Comment: but how can i make it dynamic like having  Firestore.instance.collection('products')
    .where('category', isEqualTo: categoryName)
    .where('subcategory', isEqualTo: subCategoryName) so that i would not need to  make repitition for each category and subcategory .Because i might have hundreds of category.I will surely marked your answer as a right one pls help

Comment: In that situation, you should create a list of categories. When the user selects a category, get the category name and add it to your query. Right after that create another list of subcategories, once the user selects a subcategory, add that to the query. In this way, you'll have dynamic queries, that are actually user choices.

Comment: i have idea of doing it like this Future<QuerySnapShot>(String categoryName, String SubcategoryName) {    Firestore.instance.collection('products')
    .where('category', isEqualTo: categoryName)
    .where('subcategory', isEqualTo: subCategoryName)} is it correct like that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that but without seeing the entire code, I cannot be much of a help. If you have hard time implementing that, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to display the items.
It makes sense to do as little as possible document reads.
So if you want to display all the categories and subcategories choose solution 2, if you usually only want to display one subcategory chose solution 1.

1. solution: Create a collection for each category and documents for each subcategory
2. solution: Create just one collection and a document for each category. Then use a map to sort then in subcategories and use the "where" command to get a specific subcategory.