# How to organize items on collections and subcollections on firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application for a coffee shop where their products will organized on categories and some of them in sub-categories.

We consider these two options but I do not really know if there are good alternatives.

**Option 1 - Category and subcategory collection**

This one looks like a good solution, but we still want to be sure if there are no better options. Also with this alternative we are locked with only two levels (collection and subcollection) that is something ok for now (unless requirements change).

[How to store category and subcategory in flutter Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785951/how-to-store-category-and-subcategory-in-flutter-firestore)

**Option 2 - Big map structure**
One solution was to create a big map structure, this one has the benefit to allow more subcollections, take for example this:

```json
{
    "drinks_" (category): [
        {
            "category" (sub-category): "Frappes",
            "drinks": [
                {
                "Moka": {
                    "extraSugar": false,
                    "extras": false,
                    "whipped_cream": true
                },
                "Vainilla": {
                    "extraSugar": false,
                    "extras": false,
                    "whipped_cream": true
                },
                "Oreo": {
                    "extraSugar": false,
                    "extras": false,
                    "whipped_cream": true
                }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "category" (sub-category): "Hot",
            "drinks": [
                {
                "Americano": {
                    "extraSugar": true,
                    "extras": true,
                    "whipped_cream": false
                },
                "Cappucino": {
                    "extraSugar": true,
                    "extras": true,
                    "whipped_cream": false
                },
                "Latte": {
                    "extraSugar": true,
                    "extras": true,
                    "whipped_cream": false
                }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I am new with firestore so I do not know how easy will be to work with a big map structure like seen on solution #2.

I will appreciate any feedback on these two solutions or any other ideas.

Comment: What is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: The first option has the problem that if we want to add more sub-categories in a future, then we will need to add another field to save this new sub-category option. But I think I already found another solution. I will post it later.

Comment: Ok, try to post as an answer and please add a comment using @.